# Flash - Turning Off Code Identifier Colors By Case?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, colors, identifier

sometimes Flash Authoring colors my actionscript inappropriately.  for example:  i have custom variable that i've named "closeButton".  closeButton does not reference any of the official classes yet it always colored blue as an identifier.  i'm assuming it's referencing some internal, private variable from some class in the frameworks.

is it possible to remove the color for specific identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can actually select which keywords or identifiers to be colored.

However If you have so much disregard for them, why not stop the feature altogether.

For that simply go to **Edit -> Prefrences -> Actionscript -> Code Coloring**

Also the best solution for your problem according to me is to start using FlashDevelop. It will only highlight the ones which really wanted & in addition your custom classes too.

Comment: yeah, i'm not really outraged that i can't do this in Flash Authoring.  it was a long shot.  would have been surprised if it was possible.  looks like FlashDevelop is Windows only (Mac thru emulator).  i actually own a legit copy of CS5 Web Premium, so my next step will probably be Flash Builder 4, even though i'm kind of avoid it because i think it has a seriously ugly UI.